# Mathematica: Show Complex Numbers in Polar Form

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, complex-numbers

I want to display complex numbers in trig form. For example:

```
z = (-4)^(1/4);
```

I'm not sure what the command for that is, and its silly to write:

[image]

I thought, that the command was `ExpToTrig`, but solution can't possibly be just `1+i` (Or can it, and I'm misusing it?). How do display complex number in trig form.

#### Edit:

Command is `ExpToTrig`, it just does not give all the solutions (or i have failed to find out how). Finally solved my problem with writing a pure function `NrootZpolar[n][z]`:

```
NrootZpolar := 
 Function[x, 
  Function[y, 
       ( Abs[y] ^ (1/x) *
       ( Cos[((Arg[y] + 360° * Range[0, x - 1]) / x)] + 
       I*Sin[((Arg[y] + 360° * Range[0, x - 1]) / x)]))
  ]
 ]
```

And use:

```
In[689]:= FullSimplify[NrootZpolar1[4][-4]]
Out[689]= {1 + I, -1 + I, -1 - I, 1 - I}
```

To visualize:

```
ComplexListPlot[list_] := ListPlot[Transpose[{Re[list], Im[list]}], AxesLabel -> {Re, Im}, PlotLabel -> list, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
Manipulate[ComplexListPlot[FullSimplify[NrootZpolar1[n][z]]], {z, -10, 10}, {n, 1, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: The reason your final bit of code does not give you the answer you expect is because the `/4` is in the wrong place. It should not be hitting the `Arg[x]` terms.  Move the closing brackets `)` to characters to the right and it all works.

Comment: The same mistake is made in the image you supply. btw to write out nice looking formulas you should not use a normal `Input` cell. Instead, right-click on the notebook and select `Insert New Cell > DisplayFormula`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to do it occasionally, then you could just define a function like

```
In[1]:= ComplexToPolar[z_] /; z \[Element] Complexes := Abs[z] Exp[I Arg[z]]
```

so that

```
In[2]:= z = (-4)^(1/4);
In[3]:= ComplexToPolar[z]
Out[3]= Sqrt[2] E^((I \[Pi])/4)

In[4]:= ComplexToPolar[z] == z // FullSimplify
Out[4]= True
```

For expanding out functions (not that this was part of your question) you use

```
In[5]:= ComplexExpand[, TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}]
```

Finally, if you always want complex numbers written in polar form then something like

```
In[6]:= Unprotect[Complex];
In[7]:= Complex /: MakeBoxes[Complex[a_, b_], StandardForm] := 
 With[{abs = Abs[Complex[a, b]], arg = Arg[Complex[a, b]]}, 
  RowBox[{MakeBoxes[abs, StandardForm], 
    SuperscriptBox["\[ExponentialE]", 
      RowBox[{"\[ImaginaryI]", MakeBoxes[arg, StandardForm]}]]}]]
```

will make the conversion automatic

```
In[8]:= 1 + I
Out[8]= Sqrt[2]*E^(I*(Pi/4))
```

Note that this will only work on explicitly complex numbers -- ie those with the `FullForm` of `Complex[a,b]`.  It will fail on the `z` defined above unless you use something like `Simpify` on it.

Comment: Also see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/Fz9xvjKRlsA

Answer (score 3):

You can express a complex number z in polar form r(cos theta + i sin theta) where r = Abs[z] and theta = Arg[z]. So the only Mathematica commands you need are Abs[] and Arg[].

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically speaking, (-1)^(1/4) is an abuse on notation. There is no such a number.

What you are expressing using that abomination  ( :) ) are the roots of an equation:

```
z^4 == 1
```

In Mathematica (as in math in general) is more convenient to use radians than degrees. Expressed in radians, you may define for example

```
 f[z1_,n_] := Abs[z] (Cos[Arg[z]] + I Sin[Arg[z]]) /.Solve[z^n+z1 == 0, z,Complex]
```

or

```
g[z1_,n_] := Abs[z] (Exp [I Arg[z]]) /.Solve[z^n+z1 == 0, z,Complex]
```

depending on your notation preference (trig or exponential ... but the last is preferred).

To get your desired expression for `(-4)^(1/5)`  just type

```
g[4,5] or f[4,5]
```

Comment: Yours is the only answer which addressed the probable underlying question that the OP had. i.e. the n different roots of w=z^n

Comment: @Simon I guess the problem there is not with Mathematica itself, but with understanding the "radix" operator as a multivalued inverse of the exponentiation. I tried to address that ...